# SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site Content disappears if published->accepted

Tags: sharepoint, publishing-site

The main content of our publishing site disappears after a second if the site is in published and accepted state. 
The navigation and the header is visible. The result is compareable to the problem described on this page:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_27747131.html

When you move the mouse the content appears immediately. 
The problem only occurs in Internet Explorer. 
If you check out the site the content is visible from the beginnning.

I checked for some javascript struggling, but everything seems to be ok. 
Any idea where this strange behavoir comes from?

thx for help!

Comment: it seems init.js will cause this problem. I removed every single line of custom js code and the problem still appears. The content disappears before Anonymous() function is called in init.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a very similar situation... using Sharepoint 2010 server but using MS Internet Explorer 6 (IE6) as browser, doing a quick research on the web I found the following blog with a similar discussion http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/ie6-sharepoint-2010-107662.aspx

What fixed the issue was the answer 18 down below the blog that states: "The fix: Forcing #s4-bodyContainer to have haslayout fixed everything. In my case, **adding #s4-bodyContainer { zoom: 1 }** or #s4-bodyContainer { width: 100%; } (for valid CSS) worked to fix the blank display issue AND the flyout menu positioning issues in one swoop."

Hope this helps.